# array_diff doesn't work (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array in my code, like the shown below:

```html
<?php

$kalimat = "I just want to search something like visual odometry, dude";
$kata = array();
$eliminasi = " \n . ,;:-()?!";
$tokenizing = strtok($kalimat, $eliminasi);

while ($tokenizing !== false) {
 $kata[] = $tokenizing;
 $tokenizing = strtok($eliminasi);
}
$sumkata = count($kata);
print "<pre>";
print_r($kata);
print "</pre>";


//stop list
$file = fopen("stoplist.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");
$stoplist;
$i = 0;
while($row = fgets($file)){
 $data = explode(",", $row);
 $stoplist[$i] = $data;
 $i++;
}
fclose($file);
$count = count($stoplist);

//Cange 2 dimention array become 1 dimention
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
for($j=0; $j<1; $j++){
 $stopword[$i] = $stoplist[$i][$j];
}
} 

//Filtering process
$hasilfilter = array_diff($kata,$stopword);
var_dump($hasilfilter);
?>
```

$stopword contain of some stop word like attached in http://xpo6.com/list-of-english-stop-words/

All I wanna do is: I want to check if save the element that exist in array $kata and it is not exist in array $stopword

So I want to delete all the element that exist in both array $kata and $stopword .
I read some suggestion to use array_diff , but somehow it doesn't work to me. Really need your help :( Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect us to guess contents of `$kata`, `$stopword`?

Comment: I already edit it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff` is what you need, you are right. Here is a simplified version of what you try to do:

```
<?php

// Your string $kalimat as an array of words, this already works in your example.
$kata = ['I', 'just', 'want', 'to', '...'];

// I can't test $stopword code, because I don't have your file.
// So let's say it's a array with the word 'just'
$stopword = ['just'];

// array_diff gives you what you want 
var_dump(array_diff($kata,$stopword));

// It will display your array minus "just": ['I', 'want', 'to', '...']
```

You should also double check the value of `$stopword`, I can't test this part (don't have your file). If it does not work for you, I guess the problem is with this variable (`$stopword`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `$stopword` array. var_dump it to see the issue.`array_diff` is working correct.

Try following code I wrote to make your `$stopword` array right:

```
 <?php

    $kalimat = "I just want to search something like visual odometry, dude";
    $kata = array();
    $eliminasi = " \n . ,;:-()?!";
    $tokenizing = strtok($kalimat, $eliminasi);

    while ($tokenizing !== false) {
        $kata[] = $tokenizing;
        $tokenizing = strtok($eliminasi);
    }
    $sumkata = count($kata);
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($kata);
    print "</pre>";

    //stop list
    $file = fopen("stoplist.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");
    $stoplist;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = fgets($file)){
        $data = explode(",", $row);
        $stoplist[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    $count = count($stoplist);
    //Cange 2 dimention array become 1 dimention
    $stopword= call_user_func_array('array_merge', $stoplist);
    $new = array();
    foreach($stopword as $st){
        $new[] = explode(' ', $st);
    }
    $new2= call_user_func_array('array_merge', $new);
    foreach($new2 as &$n){
        $n = trim($n);
    }
    $new3 = array_unique($new2);
    unset($stopword,$new,$new2);
    $stopword = $new3;
    unset($new3);

    //Filtering process
    $hasilfilter = array_diff($kata,$stopword);
    print "<pre>";
    var_dump($hasilfilter);
    print "</pre>";
    ?>
```

*I hope it helps*